# Parallelize all iterations of a for loop

Tags: python, time, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I need to parallelize a for loop to reduce it's execution time.
I'm replicating a database to 10 others using pymysql.

```
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error
import pymysql
import csv
import config
import multiprocessing


def query_with_fetchall(i):
    conn = MySQLConnection(host = config.host,
                                    user = config.user,
                                    password = config.passwd,
                                    db = config.db_name)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    
    sql = '''USE ultimate;
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders_user{0} (id VARCHAR(10), amazon_order_id VARCHAR(100), merchant_order_id VARCHAR(100), purchase$
    sqla = ''LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/ec2-user/order.csv' INTO TABLE orders_user{0} FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' '''
    for result in cursor.execute(sql, multi=True):
            pass
    cursor.execute(sqla)
    conn.commit()
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    print("s")

jobs = []
for i in range(2):
    try:
        p1 = Process(target = query_with_fetchall, args =(i,))
        print("done")
        jobs.append(p1)
    except Exception:
        import traceback
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        pass
for j in jobs:
    j.start()
for j in jobs:
    j.join
```

Time taken to replocate 10 tables is 10 minutes approximately i.e. 1 minute each, I want to replicate all the tables parallely in 1 minute.

Comment: What's your *specific* question?

Comment: Can't you copy the database files, like in the shell or in a file browser? Would be much faster and cleaner.

Comment: Have you tried using one thread for each loop?

Comment: @Klaus, it takes approx 1 minute to upload data to one table, when I try to do for 10 tables it takes approximately 10 minutes so I want to parallelize the process of the table creation with data and make it as fast as possible, I am using a 8 core Virtual Machine for running the code.

Comment: @Just learned it, yes that's a possible way but I want it fully automated.

Comment: @Deep Thought, actually in Python, in a threadpool, only one thread runs at a given time, basically it handles concurrent threads at the same time thus hiding latency, i guess that's because of the global interpreter lock. So multiprocessing would be the best option here, I just want to make use of all the cores parallely.

Comment: Have you also tried multiprocessing libraries in python or just the multithreading solution?

Comment: This is the code for multiprocessing that I have uploaded